# Filesystem type is ext2fs, partition type 0x83

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub

I installed Ubuntu 10.04 (LTS) to a VPS server I'm renting and get this critical error when booting:

```
Filesystem type is ext2fs, partition type 0x83
```

This prevents the rest of the boot process to continue.

When "Googling", I found no answers besides "re-install". I already tried that 3 times, and am still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Unless you're also getting an error message along with that information, I don't see what the question is.

Comment: Sorry, edited the post now. It's late here ;)

Comment: That's really the whole error? That's not really a problem; ext2 is a common filesystem choice, and partition type 0x83 is just "Linux native", which is correct as well

Comment: In addition... what virtualization product, and if you don't know that, what hosting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error, this is a standard output from GRUB. (Although in your case it could be a coincidence...)

Are you sure your `grub.cfg` / `menu.lst` is configured correctly? My GRUB normally outputs this line after the `root (hd0,X)` command...

I can't tell much more without some extra details of what software you're running, full output, and at what part of the boot process this occurs :)